# Linked List won't return to main function when head is deleted and moved forward

Tags: c, dictionary, linked-list

I'm currently stuck at this part in coding a dictionary projects. I can pretty much breeze through everything else, but here.

My problem is that whenever I return the dictionary(a linked list head) to the main function after it passes through this particular if statement, an exception pops out.

```
    item *deleteEntry(item *entry, item *dictionary)
{
    item *cont,*temp;
    int check;

    check = 0;
    for (cont = dictionary; cont != NULL; cont = cont->next)
    {
        if (!strcmp(cont->word, entry->word) && cont == dictionary)
        {
            dictionary = cont->next;
            free(cont);

            check = 1;
            break;
        }
        //other non-problematic entry-deletion statements
    }

    if (!check)
        return 0;   

    return dictionary;
}
```

Even though it does store the data correctly **inside** the function(I've tested by printing), it just doesn't work when returned to the main function.

Here's the part where I call the function

```
printf("\nEnter word to delete entry: ");
            getchar();
            fgets(entry->word, WORDLIMIT, stdin);
            if (dictionary[toupper(entry->word[0]) - 65] == NULL)
                printf("\nWord Does not exist");
            else
            {
                cont = deleteEntry(entry, dictionary[toupper(entry->word[0]) - 65]);
                if (cont)
                    dictionary[toupper(entry->word[0] - 65)] = cont;
                else
                    printf("\nError: Word doesn't exist in archive %d!!\n", toupper(entry->word[0]));
```

And the exception is :

> Access violation reading location 0xDDDDDDDD. (I don't know what this is, even after google searches. please enlighten me)

And this is my first post here, so I'll take my chance to say Thank you for this is the first place I go to whenever I get stuck :)

Problem Solved!

Comment: I'm more used to 0xCDCDCDCD (I think that was the Visual Studio standard), but something like that typically means that the compiler has stored some sentinel value (namely in your case all D's) instead of zero in uninitalized memory.  In a nutshell: you tried to read something that wasn't initialized

Comment: `dictionary = cont->next; ` does not check that  `cont->next ` is  `!= NULL `

Comment: BTW,  `dictionary[toupper(entry->word[0] - 65)]` should be `dictionary[toupper(entry->word[0]) - 65]`

Comment: @Foon that makes sense.. But I can't seem to find what. If printed on the same function, it works like it should. But if returned to main and used/printed/whatever, it doesn't. It just prints out some characters you usually relate with NULL.

Comment: @LPs 1. Seems I've kind of overlooked that one. I was trying to make the code work in the first place, so that part didn't really cross my mind yet. Thanks :D But that isn't the issue though, because the tests I use always has at least three entries: []->[]->[]->NULL that means that isn't the issue with this one =_=

Comment: @LPs 2. I'm using the ASCII idea that characters are considered numbers(I read that on this site too :D) And I found out that 'A' is 65. and since my array for sorting letters are just 0-25(Inside every element is a linked list with entries of the same first letter), that means 'A' has to be 0.  And I'm using word[0] there to compare only the first character
edit: I just read your below answer and saw where my mistake was xD

Comment: Note that you can do 'A' instead of 65 and that way you don't have to remember ASCII numbers.  (i.e. dictionary[toupper(entry->word[0]) - 'A'])

Comment: But what about when the character in question is 'B'?
edit: ok that was stupid. I just realized that it should always be 65 -_- or 'A'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented, I think the key point is `dictionary[toupper(entry->word[0] - 65)]`
This code causes to access your array of pointers out of bounds. 
E.g.

```
entry->word[0] = 'a'

toupper(entry->word[0] - 65) = 32
```

But I think that your array has 26 elements.

It must be

`dictionary[toupper(entry->word[0]) - 65]`

Comment: ^Holy... Can't believe I made a mistake like that. =_= But it finally worked!
It seems I accidentally included the **-65** in the toupper() under the if statement -_- Thank you so much, @LPs!!

Answer (score 0):

```
/* this is part of your code. check comments added by me
*/ 

 for (cont = dictionary; cont != NULL; cont = cont->next /*->next can be null*/)
{
if (!strcmp(cont->word, entry->word) && cont == dictionary)
{
dictionary = cont->next; /*if ->next above is null than boom (null->null)*/
free(cont);
check = 1;
break;
}
//other non-problematic entry-deletion statements
}


/* better use this */
cont = dictionary->next;
while(cont){
    if(...){
        dictionary=cont->next;
        free(cont);
        break; /* or return something*/
    }
    cont=cont->Next;
}
/*return other thing*/
```

Comment: 1. I used the possibility that the next can be null in the following else if statements xD 
2. That part though, is my bad =_= thanks! But since I always use at least 3 entries for testing, that isn't the issue.
3. But isn't that the exact same thing but on a while loop? enlighten me :D